# Wasn't hired back after a successful internship. The hiring manager stopped replying to me about a year ago. Should I contact again?

Tags: job-search, internship, applications, networking

I had an internship at this awesome company (a growing startup, ~150 employees) in my junior year of college. It seemed like it went really well; I got along great with everyone, my project went above and beyond expectations, I got glowing reviews during every evaluation, almost everyone in the whole company knew who I was and the work I'd done, the CEO even personally thanked me for my project. I kept in touch with my former coworkers, visited a few times as I worked through my degree, and had multiple people at the company (including my former boss, who still works there) telling me they'd love to have me back after I graduated.

When my graduation date got close, I visited again, this time to talk to the hiring manager (who I had known since my internship) about potential full-time opportunities. I thought that it went well, and they said they'd keep me in mind for future openings, but I never heard back from them again after that (and that was a year ago). I sent 2 more emails, spaced a few months apart, just to touch base again and see if things had changed, but I never got any response. I also sent in an application for a position they had open and still heard nothing back, not even a rejection. (I've done enough job applications to know that that's pretty common, it's just odd combined with everything else.)

I just wish I knew why–were they just not hiring junior devs at those times? Did I mess something up during the process that I wasn't aware of? Did they decide they weren't interested in hiring me after all? I've been hesitant to send them more emails and applications because I don't want to bother them if they've decided not to hire me, but if it was just a bad timing thing I want to keep trying. Would it be a good idea to send another email touching base again (perhaps to a separate contact that isn't the hiring manager, like my old boss)? Or continue to apply for openings I see? Or should I just let the whole thing go since I haven't talked to them in a year?

Answer (score 3):

Try sending an application to another contact (maybe call/ask first) and ask them to forward it. Don't mention any of the previous communications, there's nothing to win with pointing fingers.

If that doesn't work, forget about it, you won't get an answer out of them.

As a side note, you could try mentioning this during an interview if the above works, with someone else than the hiring manager. Any decent person would apologize. If they don't, reconsider if you want to work there, they are obviously bad at getting talented people ...

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to say whats going on, if not impossible. There could have been many things, and like you've said its possible they just aren't hiring junior devs.

There are several things you can do, the first is to reach out to other members of the company who you've worked with and ask them if they are hiring in their respective departments, you could also bring up your situation with how you've applied multiple times and just don't get a response, this could also give you a heads up as to whats going on at the company its possible that they are running out of money, they got someone for the role that you had in mind, the hiring manager isn't actually there anymore (I've had old corporate emails never be deactivated), theres a new CEO/CTO/C-level guy in charge and all hires go by him.

At the end of the day though, let bygones be bygones and move on if all else fails, its been a year and they still haven't gotten back to you, certainly there are other opportunities out there in the world.

It's also been my experience working at startups that they love to load up on interns and get free labor out of them, now that they've got to give you a salary, benefits, options,etc you just don't look so attractive anymore, but again, don't dwell on it too much move on.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective; I hadn't thought about how the hiring manager may not even *be* the hiring manager anymore. I looked her up again and it seems like she may have changed positions (although it isn't super clear), so if I do contact them again, it might be better to contact someone else.

I'm trying not to dwell on it too much, but people keep asking me why I wasn't able to get a job there and it's frustrating that I don't know for sure. But like you said, there could be a whole bunch of stuff going on, so who knows! I've just been saying they didn't have a position open.